# Weird animation happening with tableView.beginUpdates and a datePicker

Tags: swift, storyboard

In a tableView I have a button that when pressed modifies the height of the cell below it to expand and contract a datepicker so it appears and disappears. However, I am getting an odd animation bug where the picker will fluctuate and flicker when it is closing and opening.

Here is my tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 147
    } else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        if picker {
            return 216
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        return 70
    }
}
```

my button action

```
@IBAction func birthdateLabelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    picker = !picker
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

as well as the var

```
var picker: Bool = false
```

I am using storyboard to set up static cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking around I couldn't seem to find any answers to this question but I DID figure out what was going wrong.

I had my constraints situated so that Trailing Space, Leading Space, Top Space, and Bottom Space all were at -8.0.  What was happening was that when the cell was expanding and contracting the Date Picker itself was also expanding and contracting, which then would make the datePicker squish when it closed causing the flashing and odd animation.

The solution ended up being to get rid of the Bottom Space constraint and then add a Height constraint. This fixed the issue as it no longer was modifying the datePicker itself, now it just makes the datePicker invisible.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. Don't forget to accept your own answer once possible.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. I had the same problem!